What's the origin of "laughing all the way to the bank"?
What is the earliest known use of the phrase "laughing all the way to the bank?"
Liberace used the similar "cried all the way to the bank", starting in 1954 and again in his 1973 autobiography.
Did Liberace coin that variant, or did the "crying" version exist previously?

WordHoistories.net dates it back to 1908:

The phrase to laugh—also to cry—all the way to the bank means to relish—also (ironically) to deplore—the fact that one is making money, especially undeservedly or at the expense of others.
This phrase is first recorded in Peter: A Novel of Which He is Not the Hero (New York: Charles Scribner’s Sons, 1908), set in New York City’s financial world, by the American author, artist and engineer Francis Hopkinson Smith (1838-1915):

“You heard how Mason, the Chicago man, euchred the Mukton gang, didn’t you?” he had shouted to a friend one night at the Magnolia—“Oh, listen! boys. They set up a job on him,—he’s a countryman, you know a poor little countryman—from a small village called Chicago—he’s got three millions, remember, all in hard cash. Nice, quiet motherly old gentleman is Mr. Mason—butter wouldn’t melt in his mouth. Went into Mukton with every dollar he had—so kind of Mr. Breen to let him in—yes, put him down for 2,000 shares more. Then Breen & Co. began to hoist her up—five points—ten points—twenty points. At the end of the week they had, without knowing it, bought every share of Mason’s stock.” Here Garry roared, as did the others within hearing. “And they’ve got it yet. Next day the bottom dropped out. Some of them heard Mason laugh all the way to the bank. He’s cleaned up half a million and gone back home—‘so afraid his mother would spank him for being out late o’ nights without his nurse.’”


Langeek says that the origin of the variant with laugh is unknown:

The origin of the idiom "laugh all the way to the bank" is not precisely known, but it likely originated in the mid-20th century. It is used to describe the feeling of great satisfaction or triumph one experiences when they have achieved significant financial gain or success.

WordHoistories.net also gives the earliest occurrence of the variant with cry:

The earliest occurrence of the phrase that I have found is from the gossip column On Broadway, by the American journalist Walter Winchell (a.k.a. “Man About Town” – 1897-1972), published in many American newspapers in September 1946—for example on Monday 2nd in the Newark Star-Ledger (Newark, New Jersey):

Eddie Walker perhaps is the wealthiest fight manager in the game... The other night when his man Belloise lost, Eddie had the miseries... He felt so terrible, he cried all the way to the bank!


About its origin, Grammarist says:

Like so many idiomatic expressions we use, the exact origin isn’t certain. But the phrase is generally believed to be a spin-off of the phrase laughing all the way to the bank. The term gained popularity when it was used by Liberace, the famous American pianist and showman, in response to negative reviews about his performance in Madison Square Garden.

So although many refer to Liberace as to the coiner of the phrase, it is safer to say that he only popularised it, as The Irish Times puts it:

The expression "laughing all the way to the bank" is apparently a corruption of "crying all the way to the bank", popularised by piano player Liberace in the mid 1950's. The performer, prone to excesses of tearful emotion during his shows, was indicating his pleasure at being awarded £35,000 damages against the Daily Mirror.


"Laugh all the way to the bank" is an obvious expression for happiness and wealth. And the similar "laugh all the way home" is older, found in Pride and Prejudice (1813) and even earlier in the writer Henry Mackenzie c. 1780.

I thought Liberace's famous response was to being asked how he felt about implications that, to summarise, he was as camp as a row of tents. A suggestion that might have had more sting in the 1950s than now.
